# Golang program after making Get request returns HTTP Status code 503 or pending

Tags: http, go, kibana

I try to get csv data from kibana server by making get request.
After this server send me response with data which i write the csv file and save somewhere.

Every time  csv file with single line "pending" inside.

Kibana logs shows Status code 503

But if i put url in browser i can get csv file with correct data.

Probably i need to wait more for response from kibana.

From my perspective the problem is next: server can send me the response with single line "pending" which means that it needs more time for preparing right response.

I tried to increase client time but it doesn't work as well

```
client := http.Client{
    Timeout: 10 * time.Second,
}
```

The Idea with go routines and channels/wait group was next: they force Get request to wait for getting right data instead of "pending" and 503 status code

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

type KibanaReportResponse struct {
    Path string `json:"path"`
}

var urlKibanaBase = "http://localhost:5601"
var urlKibanaPost = urlKibanaBase + "/api/reporting/generate/csv_searchsource?"
var urlParameters = "jobParams=%28browserTimezone%3AEurope%2FBerlin%2Ccolumns%3A%21%28%29%2CobjectType%3Asearch%2CsearchSource%3A%28fields%3A%21%28%28field%3A%27%2A%27%2Cinclude_unmapped%3Atrue%29%29%2Cindex%3Aec074c00-1f62-11ec-8056-8d208a1f6e77%2Cparent%3A%28filter%3A%21%28%29%2Cindex%3Aec074c00-1f62-11ec-8056-8d208a1f6e77%2Cquery%3A%28language%3Akuery%2Cquery%3A%27%27%29%29%2Csort%3A%21%28%28_score%3Adesc%29%29%2CtrackTotalHits%3A%21t%2Cversion%3A%21t%29%2Ctitle%3A%27Discover%20search%20%5B2021-09-27T09%3A19%3A44.977%2B02%3A00%5D%27%29"

var urlWithParam = urlKibanaPost + urlParameters
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    pathCsvFile := getCsvPathFromKibana(urlWithParam)
    go getCsvFile(urlKibanaBase, pathCsvFile, &wg)
    defer wg.Wait()
}
func getCsvPathFromKibana(urlKib string) string {
    resKibana := KibanaReportResponse{}
    client := &http.Client{}
    if req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", urlKib, nil); err != nil {
        log.Println("Given a method, URL, andoptional body are wrong", err)
    } else {
        req.Header.Add("kbn-xsrf", "true")
        if res, err := client.Do(req); err != nil {
            log.Println("Probably problems depends on client policy or HTTP connection", err)
        } else {
            if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&resKibana); err != nil {
                log.Println("Problem by Json decoding \n", err)
            } else {
                return resKibana.Path
            }
        }
    }

    return resKibana.Path
}
func getCsvFile(urlKibanaBase string, pathCsvFile string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()

    res, err := http.Get(urlKibanaBase + pathCsvFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    switch res.StatusCode {
    case 200:
        dataBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        err = ioutil.WriteFile("data.csv", dataBody, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    case 503:
        fmt.Println("probably 503/pending")
        return errors.New("probably 503/pending")
    }

    return nil
}
```

curl request

```
curl -v localhost:5601/api/reporting/jobs/download/ku5k3rxz00xs7fac46c0k12u
```

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5601 (#0)
> GET /api/reporting/jobs/download/ku5k3rxz00xs7fac46c0k12u HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5601
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< kbn-csv-contains-formulas: true
< kbn-max-size-reached: false
< content-disposition: inline; filename="Discover search [2021-09-27T09:19:44.977+02:00].csv"
< content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
< kbn-name: 3ae0cbefece4
< kbn-license-sig: 58d9fcb437ac7d3ac54d538e6d5ff9a039fde738ed3a940fa530e6d8b6ef6740
< cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< content-length: 9013976
< vary: accept-encoding
< accept-ranges: bytes
< Date: Wed, 29 Sep 2021 14:06:19 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=120
< 
{ [13865 bytes data]
100 8802k  100 8802k    0     0  57.6M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 57.6M
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Screenshot that shows that i can get data by typing url path to the browser
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPVEK.png]

Update:

 I try to call my function recursively. But it is bad solution even if it's working now.

```
    case 503:
        getCsvFile(urlKibanaBase, pathCsvFile)
```

Comment: Probably the two requests, the one you make through the browser & the one you make using Go, are not equivalent which is why kibana replies differently to each. You should look at the browser's network tab to inspect the browser-specific request. And you should look at the dump of the Go request before sending it, and then compare it to the browser request. To dump the go request, instead of http.Get, first create it with `r, _ := http.NewRequest(...)`, then dump it with `d, _ := httputil.DumpRequestOut(r, true)`, and then print the dump `fmt.Println(string(d))`.

Comment: have you checked what `urlKibanaBase + pathCsvFile` is? e.g. `fmt.Println(urlKibanaBase + pathCsvFile)`

Comment: @TehSphinX yes, there is correct url

Comment: @mkopriva i made like u said. I opened network console and sent request to  `localhost:5601/api/reporting/jobs/download/ku5iuumi00xs7fac46b9qy4t`.Console says Status 200

Comment: @blizardinka it's not enough to be sending the request to the correct url. The headers, method, and body also matter. You need to compare the full *request message*.

Comment: @blizardinka also in the original comment I'm suggesting that you *compare* the two requests. Compare the browser request message to the Go request message. If they are exactly the same then the kibana server *has* to respond with the same response message.

Comment: @mkopriva i will try right now

Comment: @mkopriva so sorry for taking your attention. Look if i make `d, _ := httputil.DumpRequestOut(r, true)` and `fmt.Println(string(d))` i get in out just `http://localhost:5601/api/reporting/jobs/download/ku5jnx3100xs7fac46er4ues`.And after requesting in browser network tab it shows `GET /api/reporting/jobs/download/ku5iuumi00xs7fac46b9qy4t HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: @mkopriva the requests uri are different because kibana generates different urls for every request. But its now a problem cuz i tried this urls in network tab and every works fine

Comment: Here are examples where you can see not just the URI path but also the *headers* [browser (firefox)](https://imgur.com/24puhy5) & [go](https://imgur.com/LWY3HoH). The headers can be very important for a request to *succeed*. So you need to make sure that you are sending the same headers from both Go & the browser.

Comment: Maybe some authentication missing which the browser is already logged in to? Cookie, Header? (Which will show in what @mkopriva is suggesting)

Comment: @TehSphinX missing auth is definitely a possibility, although then, in general, a properly implemented HTTP server, would return a 4xx error rather than 503...

Comment: @mkopriva i made exactly what u asked. Anyway thank u for response. Is it means that if i try to make request with curl without any headers and will receive response with necessary csv file with data inside, than i dont need to specify my headers in go?

Comment: `curl localhost:5601/api/reporting/jobs/download/ku5k3rxz00xs7fac46c0k12u`  curl receive data correctly

Comment: @blizardinka depends on whether or not curl is sending some headers automatically that Go does not. You can use `-v` in curl to see the headers that `curl` sends.

Comment: <br/>GET /api/reporting/jobs/download/ku5k3rxz00xs7fac46c0k12u HTTP/1.1
<br/>Host: localhost:5601
<br/>User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 <br/>Firefox/92.0
<br/>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
<br/>Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
<br/>Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
<br/>Connection: keep-alive
<br/>Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
<br/>Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
<br/>Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
<br/>Sec-Fetch-Site: none
<br/>Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

Comment: @blizardinka try writing a simple go program that sends the request prints the response but nothing else. Single `main()` func program. Nothing else. It is possible that your actual program is doing something else that might be messing up the http communication.

Comment: @blizardinka put any large code snippets into your question (by editing it) and use formatting to make the snippet readable. The comment with the html is unreadable.

Comment: @mkopriva editing done

Comment: @blizardinka the wg specific code & the goroutine in the updated Go example doesn't actually do anything helpful, possibly all it does is cause the problem. A main like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/FVflXelqDwg) should be enough. Also it is possible that your problem is caused by `getCsvPathFromKibana` not actually returning a path that is equivalent to the path you are using in the browser. How are you generating the path when making a request through the browser? Are you using the same **exact Go code**? Or are you generating the path using some other mechanism?

Comment: @i understand what do u mean. Implantation of WaitGroup i made already afterwords and tried both variants and result is same

Comment: @mkopriva i tested already `getCsvPathFromKibana()` and it returns right path. I generate path by parsing json from kibana in `getCsvPathFromKibana()`

Comment: one of solution is to call recursively function  until data will be ready for sending. And it works. But it is very bad solution. Cuz if an amount of data will be  increased. It would destroy  my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kibana Server needs some time to prepare response.
I've added a bit of code for signaling the channel to wait some time and after waiting repeat request to client

```
if res.StatusCode != 200 {
                    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
                }
```